# Send form on enter key press with select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've a form with a select2 element (remote data example: https://select2.github.io/examples.html). I would like to send the form on enter key press in order to send the custom typed text without selecting a choice from the dropdown list. Is it possible?

Please see the attached image as example: I would like that, pressing enter key, the typed terms "text not present on the dropdown list" will be sended on the form.

Thanks

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same and found the solution on the below link

[onKeyEnterSelect2.js](https://gist.github.com/GeoffreyHervet/7fe60d552260949f97f5)

because the author of the plugin ... kills the event in case of enter click..

check the issue here [Triggering submit with enter](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1456)

Comment: **This answer only applies to Select2 3.5.x**, the events are not stopped in Select2 4.0.0 (which this question is asking about).